# Using contexts in rdflib

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I am having trouble finding a clear, sensible example of usage of context with rdflib.
ConjunctiveGraph does not accept contexts, and Graph is deprecated. How am I supposed to create and operate on different contexts within the same global ConjunctiveGraph ?

Comment: maybe I got it... let's see if I can answer my own question..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. This is the code

```
import rdflib
from rdflib.Graph import Graph

conj=rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph()

NS=rdflib.Namespace("http://example.com/#")
NS_CTX=rdflib.Namespace("http://example.com/context/#")

alice=NS.alice
bob=NS.bob
charlie=NS.charlie

pizza=NS.pizza
meat=NS.meat
chocolate=NS.chocolate

loves=NS.loves
hates=NS.hates
likes=NS.likes
dislikes=NS.dislikes

love_ctx=Graph(conj.store, NS_CTX.love)
food_ctx=Graph(conj.store, NS_CTX.food)

love_ctx.add( (alice, loves, bob) )
love_ctx.add( (alice, loves, charlie) )
love_ctx.add( (bob, hates, charlie) )
love_ctx.add( (charlie, loves, bob) )

food_ctx.add( (alice, likes, chocolate) )
food_ctx.add( (alice, likes, meat) )
food_ctx.add( (alice, dislikes, pizza) )

print "Full context"
for t in conj:
    print t

print ""
print "Contexts"
for c in conj.contexts():
    print c

print "love context"
for t in love_ctx:
    print t

print "food context"
for t in food_ctx:
    print t
```

And this is the output

```
Full context
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#hates'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#likes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#chocolate'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#likes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#meat'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#dislikes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#pizza'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'))

Contexts
<http://example.com/context/#food> a rdfg:Graph;rdflib:storage [a rdflib:Store;rdfs:label 'IOMemory'].
<http://example.com/context/#love> a rdfg:Graph;rdflib:storage [a rdflib:Store;rdfs:label 'IOMemory'].
love context
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#hates'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#charlie'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#loves'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#bob'))
food context
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#likes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#chocolate'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#likes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#meat'))
(rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#alice'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#dislikes'), rdflib.URIRef('http://example.com/#pizza'))
```